# SQL: UPDATE number of rows using another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can somebody please help me with this 'simple' query.

I have a two tables: Tunes and SavedRatings

Tunes contains a load of tune info including a Rating (INTEGER) field and an MD5 field used to uniquely identify a tune.

SavedRatings is a table consisting of a Rating and an MD5 field so that when I delete the contents of Tunes and add tunes back at a later date, I can identify the rating given to that tune.

So.. what I'm trying to do is update the Rating field in my Tunes table, by matching the Tunes MD5 field in the SavedRatings table.

I came up with the below command which is completely wrong. Can you please suggest an alternative? I'm using SQLite.

```
UPDATE Tunes
SET Tunes.Rating=SavedRatings.Rating
WHERE Tunes.MD5 IN (SELECT MD5 FROM SavedRatings);
```

Comment: I wonder what's the use of splitting this information into two tables if you want to keep it synchronous anyway :-)

Comment: @Smutje: Because I want to clear out the Tunes table regularly. When I load tunes that have been rated before, I want those tunes to be assigned a rating. The SavedRatings table content will be around 'forever'.. the Tunes table content will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

`update Tunes set Rating = ( select SavedRating.Rating from SavedRating where Tunes.md5 = SavedRating.md5)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user1101733: This does the job, thank you. I'm not sure what the "WHERE EXISTS" clause would have achieved to be honest.. Wouldn't it just stop null from being assigned if the SELECT statement returned no rows?

Comment: No, it will work even SELECT statement returns to nows. It will update only when Tunes.md5 = SavedRating.md5 is true else do nothing

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Rating = S.Rating
FROM Tunes T INNER JOIN SavedRatings S
ON T.MD5 = S.MD5
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this a try and accept your answer if it does the job.. and I'm sure it will :-)

Comment: I tried this with SQLite manager (Firefox plugin) and it gave me a syntax error which wasn't very informative. I'm sure it would be fine on MySQL though.

Comment: No this is sql server syntax mysql syntax is slightly different.

Comment: True - I just tried this in MySQL and it wouldn't work. Why can't SQL syntax be standard..

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
UPDATE Tunes
SET Tunes.Rating = SavedRatings.Rating
FROM SavedRatings 
WHERE Tunes.MD5 = SavedRatings.MD5;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this with SQLite manager as well(Firefox plugin) and it gave me a syntax error which wasn't very informative. Same problem with the other suggestion. I don't think SQLite likes the dotted notation for some reason??

Answer (score 0):

This works.. I suspect it isn't optimal but it will have to do for now until I can get a better solution:

```
UPDATE Tunes
SET Rating = ( SELECT Rating FROM SavedRatings WHERE MD5=Tunes.MD5 LIMIT 1 )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT Rating FROM SavedRatings WHERE MD5=Tunes.MD5 LIMIT 1 );
```